# How to embed Tablesaw graph in Jupyter Notebook with IJava kernel?

Tags: java, graph, jupyter-notebook

I'd like to embed [Tablesaw](https://github.com/jtablesaw/tablesaw) interactive graphs in Jupyter Notebook using the [IJava](https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava) kernel. I realize that Tablesaw may not be able to do this out of the box, but I'm willing to put in a little effort to make this happen. I'm a Java expert, but I'm new to Jupyter Notebook and to the IJava kernel, so I'm not sure where to start. Is there some API for Jupyter Notebook or for IJava for embedding objects?

First of all I installed Anaconda and then installed the IJava kernel in Jupyter Notebook with no problem. So far it's working without a hitch using OpenJDK 11 on Windows 10! Next I tried to use Tablesaw. I was able to add its Maven dependencies, load a CSV file, and create a plot. Very nice!

However to produce a graph Tablesaw generates a temporary HTML file using Plotly, and invokes the browser to show the interactive plot. In other words, the graph *does not appear inside Jupyter Notebook*.

Tablesaw has an [example with embedded graphs](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/benmccann/nbviewer-test/blob/master/Tablesaw.ipynb) using the [BeakerX](https://github.com/twosigma/beakerx) kernel (not IJava), and as you can see (scroll down to "Play (Money)ball with Linear Regression"), they are embedding a Tablesaw `Plot` *directly within Jupyter Notebook*. So I know that conceptually embedding an interactive Tablesaw graph in Jupyter Notebook with a Java kernel is possible.

Is this capability something specific to BeakerX? I would switch to BeakerX, but from the documentation I didn't see anything about BeakerX support Java 9+. In addition IJava seemed like a leaner implementation, built directly on top of JShell.

Where do I start to figure out how to embed a Tablesaw `Plot` object as an interactive graph in Jupyter Notebook using the IJava kernel, the way they are doing in BeakerX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IJava kernel has 2 main functions for `display_data`; `display` and `render`. Both hook into the `Renderer` from the [base kernel](https://github.com/SpencerPark/jupyter-jvm-basekernel). We can register a render function for the `Figure` type from tablesaw.

1. Add the tablesaw-jsplot dependency (and all required transitive dependencies) via the `loadFromPOM` cell magic:

   ```xml
   %%loadFromPOM
   <dependency>
       <groupId>tech.tablesaw</groupId>
       <artifactId>tablesaw-jsplot</artifactId>
       <version>0.30.4</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Register a render function for `IJava`'s renderer.

   1. We create a registration for `tech.tablesaw.plotly.components.Figure`.
   2. If an output type is not specified during the render then we want it to default to `text/html` (with the `preferring` call).
   3. If an html render is requested, we build the target `<div>` as well as the javascript that invokes a plotly render into that `<div>`. Most of this logic is done via tablesaw's `asJavascript` method but hooks into Jupyter notebook's `require` AMD module setup.

   ```
   import io.github.spencerpark.ijava.IJava;

   IJava.getKernelInstance().getRenderer()
       .createRegistration(tech.tablesaw.plotly.components.Figure.class)
       .preferring(io.github.spencerpark.jupyter.kernel.display.mime.MIMEType.TEXT_HTML)
       .register((figure, ctx) -> {
           ctx.renderIfRequested(io.github.spencerpark.jupyter.kernel.display.mime.MIMEType.TEXT_HTML, () -> {
               String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "");

               figure.asJavascript(id);
               Map<String, Object> context = figure.getContext();

               StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
               html.append("<div id=\"").append(id).append("\"></div>\n");
               html.append("<script>require(['https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.44.4.min.js'], Plotly => {\n");
               html.append("var target_").append(id).append(" = document.getElementById('").append(id).append("');\n");
               html.append(context.get("figure")).append('\n');
               html.append(context.get("plotFunction")).append('\n');
               html.append("})</script>\n");
               return html.toString();
           });
       });
   ```
3. Then we can create a table to display (taken from the [Tablesaw docs](https://jtablesaw.github.io/tablesaw/gettingstarted)).

   ```java
   import tech.tablesaw.api.*;
   import tech.tablesaw.plotly.api.*;
   import tech.tablesaw.plotly.components.*;

   String[] animals = {"bear", "cat", "giraffe"};
   double[] cuteness = {90.1, 84.3, 99.7};

   Table cuteAnimals = Table.create("Cute Animals")
       .addColumns(
           StringColumn.create("Animal types", animals),
           DoubleColumn.create("rating", cuteness)
       );
   cuteAnimals
   ```
4. Finally we can create a `Figure` for the table and display it via one of 3 methods for displaying things in IJava.

   ```java
   VerticalBarPlot.create("Cute animals", cuteAnimals, "Animal types", "rating");
   ```

   which is equivalent to a `render` call where the `"text/html"` is implicit because we set it as the preferred type (`preferring` during registration)

   ```java
   render(VerticalBarPlot.create("Cute animals", cuteAnimals, "Animal types", "rating"), "text/html");
   ```

   and if it is not at the end of a cell, the `display` function is another option. For example to display the chart and the `cuteAnimals` afterwards:

   ```java
   Figure figure = VerticalBarPlot.create("Cute animals", cuteAnimals, "Animal types", "rating");
   display(figure);

   cuteAnimals
   ```

Comment: Wonderful!! Thanks for all your work on this, SpencerPark. It is everything I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try using the command prompt and using pip install Tablesaw, then use other suggestions.